# Replace last character of a matched string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am need to post-process lines in a file by replacing the last character of string matching a certain pattern.

The string in question is:

```
BRDA:2,1,0,0
```

I'd like to replace the last digit from 0 to 1. The second and third digits are variable, but the string will always start BRDA:2 that I want to affect.

I know I can match the entire string using regex like so

```
/BRDA:2,\d,\d,1
```

How would I get at that last digit for performing a replace on?

Thanks

Comment: Use [`s.replace(/(BRDA:2,\d+,\d+,)\d+/, "$11")`](https://regex101.com/r/qTgUAo/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match and *capture* the parts of the string with capturing groups to be able to restore those parts in the replacement result later with *backreferences*. What you need to replace/remove should be just matched.

So, use

```js
var s = "BRDA:2,1,0,0"
s = s.replace(/(BRDA:2,\d+,\d+,)\d+/, "$11")
console.log(s)
```

If you need to match the *whole string* you also need to wrap the pattern with `^` and `$`:

```
s = s.replace(/^(BRDA:2,\d+,\d+,)\d+$/, "$11")
```

**Details**:

- `^` - a start of string anchor
- `(BRDA:2,\d+,\d+,)` - Capturing group #1 matching:

  - `BRDA:2,` - a literal sunstring `BRDA:2,`
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `,` - a comma
  - `\d+,` - 1+ digits and a comma
- `\d+`  - 1+ digits.

The replacement - `$11` - is parsed by the JS regex engine as the `$1` backreference to the value kept inside Group 1 and a `1` digit.